# ASP NET Core Web API returning a link to an image failing

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a working ASP.NET Web API.  I am currently converting it to ASP.NET Core 3.1.

In one of the API calls, I check if an image is present in a folder.  If it is not, I create it (in code) and then send a link to it (amongst other things) back to the caller.  The check if exists and creation of the image works fine in ASP.NET Core, but when I send back the link to the image, the client does not find it and hence it appears as a broken link on their web page.

See this diagram for the structure and for example the EnabledTRImage.png file.

[image]

The Url I am returning is:

```
http://localhost:59682/TR/128/EnabledTRImage.png
```

I have also tried returning:

```
http://localhost:59682/wwwroot/TR/128/EnabledTRImage.png
```

But this fails too.

One thing I have noticed is that in ASP.NET Core, creating the image in code makes it part of the Project, whereas in ASP.NET it does not.  I was wondering if that had anything to do with the issue.

Unfortunately, these images are central to the Web API.  So I am stuck.

Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: When it "fails" what exactly happens? Is there an error message? What status code does the browser report?

Comment: The calling page in Chrome contains the following <img src="http://localhost:59682/TR/128/EnabledTRImage.png" class="js-cell" style="cursor: pointer;" data-isenabled="true" alt="Enabled Matrix Cell" title="Toggle enabled/disabled">  as expected, but the image does not show in the Browser.

Comment: Also, if I just paste that link in the Browser the image does not show.

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed it myself.  I had not specified:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

In the Startup/Configure method.  That line is not there in the WebApi template (as expected I guess)

Answer (score 0):

In the Startup/Configure method.

Instead of `app.UseStaticFiles();`

Specify your folder path in `StaticFileOptions()`

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions(){
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"ProductImagesFiles")),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/ProductImagesFiles")
    });
```

'[image]